# Where else can I get Rinkeby Ether apart from faucet.rinkeby.io/

Tags: ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, tokens, rinkeby

I have been trying to get rinkeby ether from faucet.rinkeby.io/ but couldn't. Any alternative?

Comment: If resolved click tick mark

Answer (score 1):

There are couple for solutions

1. [Tweet](https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Requesting%20faucet%20funds%20into%200x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000%20on%20the%20%23Rinkeby%20%23Ethereum%20test%20network)
2. http://rinkeby-faucet.com/
3. Post URL in Google+
4. Post URL in facebook