# How long does it take to get the eth from Rinkeby after submitting to Twitter?

Tags: rinkeby

I asked for the 3 day one, but I am not sure if that means I will get it in 3 days or that I can't get more in 3 days. It's been over 24 hours and my balance is still 0 and when I try and submit to get more it tells me I have to wait.

Comment: Nobody gives away money for free. Assume that everybody on twitter is a scammer.

Comment: Dang it I just realized I didn’t put Rinkeby in the title

Comment: get Rinkeby test token is painfull. write your public key and i will send you 0.4 R Ether

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where else can I get Rinkeby Ether apart from faucet.rinkeby.io/](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/39478/where-else-can-i-get-rinkeby-ether-apart-from-faucet-rinkeby-io)